# One column headings in twocolumn environment

Tags: sectioning, two-column

In a `twocolumn` document, I would like chapter headings that span on two columns but don't introduce a page break:

- `section` doesn't introduce a page break, but it doesn't span on two columns;
- `chapter` spans on two columns but introduces a page break (even double page break);
- I can't use `multicols` because I'm using floats in my columns.

Comment: You're out of luck, I'm afraid.

Comment: Do I get a badge for exhausting @egreg's well of TeX wisdom?

Comment: Ask the LaTeX3 team to push development of `xor`. ;-)

Comment: I guess I'll have to give up on my floats then… they're really causing too much trouble :(

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid you're out of luck: `twocolumn` doesn't balance columns, only `multicols` does. But floats are not allowed in `multicols`.

We all hope the development of `xor` (the new output routine for LaTeX3) can be pushed forward.